# Fileinfo extension Google App Engine + Intervention/Image

Tags: php, google-app-engine, intervention

I am looking to use the **intervention/image** + **laravel** in my application on **Google App Engine (GAE)**, but to use the **Intervention/Image** I need to enable **fileinfo extension**, but I do not know how to do it in **GAE** ... I tried to create a **php.ini** and enable it did not work.

Can anyone help me?

I thank the attention.

Comment: This question needs more details from the user, but I can at least remove the python tag that has nothing to do with this question

Comment: Unfortunately fileinfo is not [one of the enabled extensions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions) on GAE. Please file a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language=PHP

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but maybe someone will find this useful.

The extension is available on GAE since [November 30, 2015](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/release-notes#1.9.29).

All you need to do to use it is enabled it in your `php.ini`:

`extension = "fileinfo.so"`

More information about the dynamically loaded extensions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions).